# Railo WAR on Tomcat application root mapping doesn't seem to work

Tags: tomcat, coldfusion, railo

I have added the Railo WAR onto a Tomcat server and am testing an application we have.

The application is in

```
/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/railo-4.1.2.005/app/
```

I have a file I wish to include in

```
/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/railo-4.1.2.005/app/public/test/example.cfm
```

When I attempt to set a mapping in the file

```
/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/railo-4.1.2.005/app/public/Application.cfc
```

With the code

```
this.mappings["/"] = reverse(listRest(reverse(getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath())), "\/")) & "/";
```

---

So when I try to include the example file in the Application.cfc onRequestStart()

```
<cfinclude template="/public/test/example.cfm" />
```

I get an error

> Page /public/test/example.cfm [/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/railo-4.1.2.005/public/test/example.cfm] not found

As you can see, the "/" mapping did not seem to take. And the application is assuming "/" is "/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/railo-4.1.2.005/" instead of "/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/railo-4.1.2.005/app/". The same can be seen using ExpandPath("/").

Also, this code works in Adobe Coldfusion 9 and 10.

Comment: You may want to ask this on the railo mailing list, you'll probably receive an answer there.

Comment: Interesting side effect of a WAR maybe.
I ran your code on cflive, to get the paths, and like you said, that should get you the right path for the mapping. 
I wonder if the WAR by default maps the / for you... and maybe they're conflicting. 
Can you map using that code for another mapping, like /testmapping/ just to see if that works... and see if its the WAR mappings, or if its just the / mapping.
Matt is right, maybe someone on the Railo list can help you with this.

Comment: So I posted to the mailing list and no one seemed to be interested. Any ideas on settings to change until I find the right one?